# Trivial Python Snippet/Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

He defines the following Python function normally:

```
def findMax (team, board, MIN, MAX, levels)
    ...
    ...
    return
```

In his program he calls it this way:

```
myValue = findMax(team, board, MIN, MAX, 3) [1]
```

and it works properly.  But if I remove the bracketed 1 and call it like this:

```
myValue = findMax(team, board, MIN, MAX, 3)
```

it throws this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple.
```

My question is this:  What is the bracketed 1 doing?  I have never seen a bracketed number following arguments in a called function and I can't find the answer anywhere in the Python literature.

Comment: You omitted the body of `findMax`. Does it return a list?

Comment: That depends on what exactly `findMax()` is returning. If it's returning an iterable, then that `[1]` is accessing the second item in that iterable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[1]` is a [*subscription expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions). `findMax()` returns a *list*, and `[1]` picks out a single element from that sequence, the one with index 1.

When you remove the `[1]` expression, you get the `TypeError` later on when code that expected a different type of object, but is now given that list instead.

Perhaps you found the space between the `)` of the `findMax()` call and the `[1]` confusing. It is much better to leave out that space, and the [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) states no spaces should be used there, but spaces are perfectly legal there:

```
>>> l = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> l[1]
'bar'
>>> l [1]
'bar'
>>> l             [1]
'bar'
```

Legal, but confusing to new coders.

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation.